# How to get the ray that faces Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

two days I'm trying to get a proper ray from the camera.

I have a script to simulate recoil of a gun that rotates the Camera of the built-in FirstPersonCharacter of Unity. It rotates with a simple `cam.transform.Rotate(X, 0, 0);`
But I can't manage to get a good ray from there, the `cam.transform.forward` is horizontal like if the camera were not rotated and cam.ViewportToWorldPoint doesn't work neither.

Do you guys have any idea about how could I get it to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rotate camera with cam.transform.Rotate(0,y,0) you rotate your camera around Y-axis. Which basically means that your camera remains horizontal, but rotates to the left and to the right (probably not the best way to simulate recoil).

To rotate your camera vertically in the way resembling recoil, you should probably lerp your camera.transform.forward to camera.transform.up with a certain coefficient, like 0.5f or something.

UPDATE, some example code:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        var direction = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.forward, Camera.main.transform.up, 0.1f);
        Camera.main.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position + direction);
        var ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean on X axis ^^', is forward writable, isn't it read  only ? By editing, it, it doesn't rotate the camera

Comment: Thanks :), I'm looking at making it smoother atm

Comment: Huuge issue is that while recoiling, i can't move to the left or right due to the lookAt every frame (every frame for it to be smoother)

Comment: This LookAt takes into account your current camera position/rotation. This means that if you moved to the left or right already this frame, LookAt will not override your movement, but add some vertical movement to it.